# Prefix match with MySQL index: LIKE word% vs. MATCH 'word*' for search results autocomplete

Tags: mysql, search, autocomplete, full-text-search

I'm trying to decide between two options to achieve a prefix match for names (50 Millions options) with MySQL. The usage is for an autocomplete for search results. The dilemma is between building:

1. An index on the VARCHAR and performing a LIKE 'word%' query
2. A FTS (full text search) index and performing a MATCH 'word*' query

Which is better for such a case? Should I consider additional FTS features for such an auto-suggest autocomplete of names?

Comment: My first though is that full-text index is used for massive text content while VARCHAR is used for smaller names. If full-text index were best even for smaller cases, then everyone would use it. Since that's not the case this simply depends on how much text you will have in the column per row.

Comment: vote for 1st:

1. An index on the VARCHAR and performing a LIKE 'word%' query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FTS and prefix matching are two different things.  So the answer depends on what your actual requirement is.

Do you need to return a list of all results that exactly match the condition `column LIKE 'word%'`?  Specifically that the string must start with the word you're looking for.

Full text search does matching based on relevance.  It's not always going to give you things that match specific strings.  It does stemming, it has stopwords, it omits results if a word is too common.

I think in this case the best answer is "Full text search doesn't quite do what you think it does"  So if you have precise requirements for matching, you should stick to the method that will work.

Comment: Do you believe a search autocomplete will benefit from the FTS relevance based matching? The autocomplete is on a list of people's names (50Millions).

Comment: no, I don't think a typeahead/autocomplete would benefit from FTS.  Just remember if you're implementing it with prefix based matching, make sure you have a minimum word size like 3-5 characters, and use a query like: SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'word%' ORDER BY name LIMIT 5;

Comment: given an index on the name column, the order by + limit would make sure the query doesn't scan too many rows, and become a huge performance problem.